# How can I move the text 'Github' under the Text 'John Doe'?

Tags: html, css

[Screenshot of my page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKK6O.png) I want to know how I can position the text 'Github' under 'John Doe'.

```css
    body {
      background-color: #000000;
      height: 700px;
    }
    h1 {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 50px;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    h3 {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #ff384b;
     }
    br {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #ff384b;
    }
    .container {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      position: sticky;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
My HTML File:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"> </link>
      <title> John Doe </title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>John Doe</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="conatiner2">
        <h3> Github </h3>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I describe my problem more in detail. The name John Doe is centred. And I want the text 'Github' directly under it. But how can I achieve that? When I try to do it, 'Github' is centred but on the end of the page. Can someone help me please? Btw I never used CSS before.

Comment: Where is "Github" in your HTML file? Or are you looking for a way to just generally create a new element containing the text Github?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the div with 'Github'. I just want to know how to position it under the Text 'John Doe'.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your final result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you wanted? I have put the the Github under Text 'John Doe'.

```css
body {
      background-color: #000000;
      height: 700px;
    }
    h1 {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 50px;
      color: #ffffff;
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 48px;
    }
    h3 {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #ff384b;
      margin: 0;
     }
    br {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #ff384b;
    }
    .container {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      position: sticky;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"> </link>
      <title> John Doe </title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>John Doe</h1>
        <h3> Github </h3>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Or something like this?

```css
body {
      background-color: #000000;
      height: 700px;
    }
    h1 {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 50px;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    h3 {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #ff384b;
     }
    br {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #ff384b;
    }
    .container {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      position: sticky;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .container2 {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"> </link>
      <title> John Doe </title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>John Doe</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="container2">
        <h3> Github </h3>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: More like the first one. But can you put Github directly under John Doe, just like a new line?

Comment: Edited the answer, let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `container` class for Github as you did for John Doe (classes are not unique and can be shared among multiple elements)

```
<div class="container">
  <h3> Github </h3>
</div>
```

Also remove `height: 100%;` from your CSS file under `.container` in order to get the text to appear closer together. Both will be centered on the page based on your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes...

1) Move the 'Github' text into the same container as 'John Doe' so that they are formatted together.

2) Remove all of this:
      display: flex;
      position: sticky;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;

3) Replace it with...
text-align center: // (centers the text)
margin: 0 auto; // (centers the content to the middle of the screen)

```css
    body {
      background-color: #000000;
      height: 700px;
    }
    h1 {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 50px;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    h3 {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #ff384b;
     }
    br {
      font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #ff384b;
    }
    .container {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
My HTML File:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"> </link>
      <title> John Doe </title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>John Doe</h1>
        <h3>Github</h3>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```